# How to get Data from firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

i design my firebase structure and i'm trying to get some data from it.
first, i explain what my app(in ionic 2) and if anyone has any idea how can i design it in another way, i will be happy to hear.
so i have some departments (like software engineering, chemistry engineering) , each department has his one courses. each courses can be in semester A, B,C.
so this is what i did.
[image]

in departments i have id and name, then i save into the Courses the id of the department and into that i put SemA, SemB for example. each Sem has own courses.

i want to make some queries:

1. the green sign: get the data from semA, i did like that but it's not working

   let courses=firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA');
2. the orange sing: get data of SemaA and SemB, i did like that but it's not working also

   let courses=firebase.database().ref('Courses/'+departmentId);

how can i do that?
any one has another way to design my firebase structure?

Comment: 1. Please copy the relevant JSON data as text instead of attaching an image. 2. Please define "not working" and include the code that is not behaving as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to listen for this data changing or only getting it once?  If you only need the data once you could try this.

```
let semesterA = firebase.database()
                    .ref('Courses/'+departmentId+'/SemA')
                    .once('value).then(function(snapshot) {
                        // do what you need to with your snapshot here.
                        console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

And for all the courses

```
let courses = firebase.database()
                    .ref('Courses/'+departmentId)
                    .once('value).then(function(snapshot) {
                        // do what you need to with your snapshot here.
                        console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```